# Trouble referencing sheet code names

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Here's the basic problem: I am writing an Excel macro and I would like to use the worksheet code names to try to eliminate any errors down the road. I can use the code name for Sheet1 and it works fine, but when I try to use the other codes, like Sheet3 or Sheet7 the editor doesn't recognize them and if I run the macro Excel kicks up an error telling me that my "variable is not defined".

For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim SheetObject As Worksheet
Dim SheetObject2 As Worksheet

Set SheetObject = Sheet1
Set SheetObject2 = Sheet3

MsgBox (SheetObject.Name)
MsgBox (SheetObject2.Name)


End Sub
```

If I comment out any code referring to SheetObject2 the macro runs correctly. If I put them in I get the errors. I definitely have a Sheet3, and the code name is definitely Sheet3. I've looked around Google all day and can't seem to come up with any solutions, any help would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Jesse

Comment: Are you sure 'Sheet3' is the actual sheet code name?  Try looping through each sheet and printing the real code names to see if they match like this: `For Each wks In Worksheets
        Debug.Print wks.CodeName
    Next wks`  or just try using the name like this: `Set SheetObject2 = Worksheets("Sheet3")`

Comment: Try this:                                                       `For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
Debug.Print "sheet name = " & Worksheets(i).Name & vbCr _
& "code name = " & Worksheets(i).CodeName & vbCr
Next`

Comment: `Set SheetObject = Sheets(1)`, or `Set SheetObject = Sheets("Sheet1")` , both are ok, the first being its index , the laste its name.

Comment: (1) I cannot duplicate your problem. I started with the default three worksheets and added a few more. I was able to initialise a worksheet object using the code names of each of these worksheets and was then able to access their names without any errors. (2) What problem do you believe you can avoid by using code names rather than the regular name that the user can see on the worksheet tab?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I think I might have figured it out. The code name cannot be used to reference sheets in other workbooks. My macro was in my personal workbook and I was attempting to reference the sheet in the workbook I processing. I was staring at my screen and it suddenly hit me what I was doing! @Tony Dallimore - The workbook I am processing is generated by another company, and I wanted to attempt to make my code error resistant if they changed the sheet names in the future.

Comment: In my experience, change in worksheet name is the least likely problem with workbooks that are controlled by others. Extra columns, resequenced columns and changed heading rows are much more common. Your code much check that each workbook you receive matches your expectation. If you expect worksheets "A" and "B", check they exist. If you expect column headings "Xxxx", "Yyyyy" and "Zzzz", check them. The objective is for your code to fail with a suitable error message before it does something with data that it not what you expect.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of error prevention from that perspective, but you're correct, it makes more sense to check rather than blindly trust that the data is there. Thanks for taking the time to explain

Comment: This is your question so you are informed if a comment or answer is posted against it.  The poster of the comment is only told you have replied if you include @UserName in the reply.  You included my name in an earlier reply; it is important you always remember to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last employer collected data and created national statistics.  Much of that data came in the form of Excel workbooks so I have had a lot of relevant experience.

If you are running your own macro and if this is a one-off exercise then tests like this may be adequate:

```
Debug.Assert WbookTgt.WsheetTgt.Range("A1").Value = "Date"
```

Many languages have an *Assert statement* as a development aid; this is the VBA version.  If the assertion is not true, the macro will stop with this statement highlighted.

If this approach is not adequate, you should consider developing parameterised macros that perform checking and updating tasks.  I have looked through some of my old macros but most would not be intelligible to someone new to VBA.  I have extracted code to create two macros which I hope will give you some ideas.

**Macro 1 - OpenWorkbook**

Organisations that regularly supply data often use names like: "Xxxxx 1409.xlsx" and "Xxxxx 1410.xlsx" for the September and October versions of their data.  You could, for example, update the macro each month for the latest name or you could change the filename to a standard value.  Either of these possibilities would be a nuisance and I would be particularly opposed to the second idea because I like to archive all the workbooks I have processed.

OpenWorkbook() uses the Dir statement to search a folder for a file that matches a template such as “Xxxxx*.xls*”.  If a single file matches this template, the macro opens the workbook and returns a reference to it.

**Macro 2 – CheckWorksheets**

You may have noticed that some VBA routines have a fixed number of parameters while others have a variable number of parameters.  For example, the following are all valid calls of CheckWorksheets:

```
If CheckWorksheets(WbookTgt, WbookThis, “Name1”) then
If CheckWorksheets(WbookTgt, WbookThis, “Name1”, “Name2”) then
If CheckWorksheets(WbookTgt, WbookThis, “Name1”, “Name2”, “Name3”) then
```

CheckWorksheets has three parameters.  The first two are workbook references.  The third is `ParamArray SheetName() As Variant`.  Any parameter after the first two is placed in array SheetName which can be as large as necessary.  Here all the trailing parameters are strings but they could be of any type.

I can use OpenWorkbook to open this month’s version of the source file and then use CheckWorksheets to confirm all the worksheets required by my macro are present.

**Worksheet Errors”**

These two macros require a worksheet Errors be present in a specified workbook.  If the macros detect an error, they add a detailed error message to this worksheet.  I have found this a convenient technique for capturing the details of any errors.

**Macros Demo1 and Demo2**

I have included two macros that demonstrate the use of these macros with workbooks on my system.  If you amend Demo1 and Demo2 to operate on some of your workbooks, you should get an idea of what OpenWorkbook and CheckWorksheets can do for you.

Come back with questions as necessary but the more you can decipher OpenWorkbook and CheckWorksheets yourself, the faster you will develop your own skills

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo1()

  Dim Path As String
  Dim WbookThis As Workbook
  Dim WbookTgt As Workbook

  ' Application.ThisWorkbook identifies the workbook containing this macro.
  Set WbookThis = Application.ThisWorkbook

  ' I find it convenient to place my target workbooks in the folder
  ' holding the workbook containing the macro(s).
  Path = WbookThis.Path

  Set WbookTgt = OpenWorkbook(Path, "Combined*.xls*", WbookThis)

  If WbookTgt Is Nothing Then
    ' Detailed error message already recorded in "Errors"
    Call MsgBox("Wokbook failed checks", vbOKOnly)
  Else
    With WbookTgt
      Debug.Print .Path & "\" & .Name & " opened."
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
  End If

End Sub
Sub Demo2()

  Dim Path As String
  Dim WbookThis As Workbook
  Dim WbookTgt As Workbook

  ' Application.ThisWorkbook identifies the workbook containing this macro.
  Set WbookThis = Application.ThisWorkbook

  ' I find it convenient to place my target workbooks in the folder
  ' holding the workbook containing the macro(s).
  Path = WbookThis.Path

  Set WbookTgt = OpenWorkbook(Path, "Combined 2.04.xls*", WbookThis)

  If WbookTgt Is Nothing Then
    ' Detailed error message already recorded in "Errors"
    Call MsgBox("Wokbook failed checks", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If
  With WbookTgt
    If Not CheckWorksheets(WbookTgt, WbookThis, "Critical Path", "Dyn Dims") Then
      Call MsgBox("Wokbook failed checks", vbOKOnly)
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
      Exit Sub
    End If
    Debug.Print .Path & "\" & .Name & " contains worksheets Critical and Dym Dims"
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With

End Sub
Function CheckWorksheets(ByRef WbookTgt As Workbook, ByRef WbookError As Workbook, _
                         ParamArray SheetName() As Variant) As Boolean

  ' * Return True if WbookTgt contains every specified worksheet.

  ' * WbookTgt is the workbook to be checked
  ' * WbookError identifies the workbook containing worksheet "Error" to which any
  '   error message will be added.
  ' * SheetName() is an array of worksheet names.

  Dim ErrorMsg As String
  Dim FoundError As Boolean
  Dim FoundSheet() As Boolean
  Dim FoundSheetsCount As Long
  Dim InxName As Long
  Dim InxWsheet As Long
  Dim NotFoundSheetsCount As Long
  Dim RowErrorNext As Long
  Dim SheetNamesFound As String

  ' Size FoundSheet to match SheetName.  Array elements initialised to False
  ReDim FoundSheet(LBound(SheetName) To UBound(SheetName))

  FoundSheetsCount = 0
  NotFoundSheetsCount = 0
  With WbookTgt
    For InxName = LBound(SheetName) To UBound(SheetName)
      NotFoundSheetsCount = NotFoundSheetsCount + 1   ' Assume not found until found
      For InxWsheet = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        If SheetName(InxName) = .Worksheets(InxWsheet).Name Then
          FoundSheet(InxName) = True
          FoundSheetsCount = FoundSheetsCount + 1
          NotFoundSheetsCount = NotFoundSheetsCount - 1
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End With

  If NotFoundSheetsCount = 0 Then
    CheckWorksheets = True
    Exit Function
  End If

  SheetNamesFound = ""
  ErrorMsg = WbookTgt.Path & "\" & WbookTgt.Name & " does not contain "
  If NotFoundSheetsCount = 1 Then
    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & "this expected worksheet:"
  Else
    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & "these expected worksheets:"
  End If
  For InxName = LBound(SheetName) To UBound(SheetName)
    If Not FoundSheet(InxName) Then
      ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & vbLf & "  " & SheetName(InxName)
    Else
      SheetNamesFound = SheetNamesFound & vbLf & "  " & SheetName(InxName)
    End If
  Next
  If FoundSheetsCount = 0 Then
    ' No need to add list of found sheet names
  Else
    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & vbLf & "but does contain "
    If FoundSheetsCount = 1 Then
      ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & "this expected worksheet:"
    Else
      ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & "these expected worksheets:"
    End If
    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & SheetNamesFound
  End If
  With WbookError
    With .Worksheets("Errors")
      RowErrorNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
      With .Cells(RowErrorNext, "A")
        .Value = Now()
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
      End With
      .Cells(RowErrorNext, "B").Value = ErrorMsg
    End With
  End With
  CheckWorksheets = False

End Function
Function OpenWorkbook(ByVal Path As String, ByVal FileTemplate As String, _
                      ByRef WbookError As Workbook) As Workbook

  ' * If Path & FileTemplate identifies a single workbook, open it and return
  '   it as an object.  If Path & FileTemplate does not represent a single
  '   workbook, report the problem in worksheet Errors and return Nothing.

  ' * WbookError identifies the workbook containing worksheet "Error".
  ' * Path must be the name of the folder in which the required workbook is located
  ' * FileTemplate can either be a specific filename or can contain wild cards
  '   providing only one file matches the template.
  ' * WbookError identifies the workbook containing worksheet "Error" to which any
  '   error message will be added.

  Dim ErrorMsg As String
  Dim FileNameCrnt As String
  Dim FileNameMatch As String
  Dim RowErrorNext As Long

  FileNameMatch = Dir$(Path & "\" & FileTemplate, vbNormal)
  If FileNameMatch = "" Then
    ' No matches found
    ErrorMsg = "Template " & Path & "\" & FileTemplate & " does not match any file"
  Else
    ' At least one match.
    ' If only one match, its name is in FileNameMatch
    Do While True
      FileNameCrnt = Dir$
      If FileNameCrnt = "" Then
        ' No more matches
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' A second or subsequent match has been found.
      If FileNameMatch <> "" Then
        ' This is the second match.
        ' Initialise error message and report name of first match
        ErrorMsg = "Template " & Path & "\" & FileTemplate & " matches more than one file:" & _
                   vbLf & "  " & FileNameMatch
        FileNameMatch = ""      ' No single match
      End If
      ' Add name of current match to error message
      ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & vbLf & "  " & FileNameCrnt
    Loop
  End If

  If FileNameMatch = "" Then
    ' No single match found.
    ' ErrorMsg contains an appropriate error message
    With WbookError
      With .Worksheets("Errors")
        RowErrorNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With .Cells(RowErrorNext, "A")
          .Value = Now()
          .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        End With
        .Cells(RowErrorNext, "B").Value = ErrorMsg
        Set OpenWorkbook = Nothing
      End With
    End With
  Else
    ' Single match found
    Set OpenWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileNameMatch)
  End If

End Function
```

**Response to extra question**

VBA has nothing quite as convenient as VB's `Try` but it does have some error handling under programmer control.

If you use a command such as:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
```

the user will be asked to confirm the deletion. To avoid this, use:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I have seen code with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the start of a macro which means no alert will be displayed for the user's attention even if the pogrammer was not expecting it. By bracketing the `Delete`, I ensure only the alert I was expecting is suppressed.

Consider:

```
Sub OpenFile()
  Dim InputFileNum As Long
  InputFileNum = FreeFile
  Open "Dummy.txt" For Input As InputFileNum
  Debug.Print "File successfully opened"
  Close InputFileNum
End Sub
```

The file "Dummy.txt" does not exist so the macro will stop on the `Open` statement.

You will sometimes see code like this:

```
Sub OpenFile()

  Dim InputFileNum As Long

  On Error GoTo ErrorCode

  InputFileNum = FreeFile
  Open "Dummy.txt" For Input As InputFileNum
  Call MsgBox("File successfully opened", vbOKOnly)
  Close InputFileNum
  Exit Sub

ErrorCode:
  Debug.Print "Unexpected error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Here I have provided a general handler for any error condition that may occur. I do not approve although I accept that this is slightly better than having the non-technical user seeing the faulty statement highlighted.  The trouble is any error will result in the same unhelpful error message.

I never include error handling during development. If an error occurs, I want the macro to stop on the faulty statement so I can consider how to avoid the error.  Here I should check the file exists before attempting to open it. I prefer something like this:

```
Sub OpenFile()

  Dim FileSysObj As Object
  Dim InputFileNum As Long

  On Error GoTo ErrorCode

  Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If Not FileSysObj.FileExists("Dummy.txt") Then
    Call MsgBox("I am unable to find ""Dummy.txt"".  List of helpful suggestions.", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  InputFileNum = FreeFile
  Open "Dummy.txt" For Input As InputFileNum
  Call MsgBox("File successfully opened", vbOKOnly)
  Close InputFileNum
  Exit Sub

ErrorCode:
  Debug.Print "Unexpected error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

I have including checking code for the error I expect. If the file does not exist, I have displayed a message which I hope will help the user fix the problem for themselves.

Sometimes you cannot avoid an error. To test the code below, I created file Dummy.txt but set the "Read access denied" flag. There is no easy method (to my knowledge) for a VBA macro to test this flag. I have a general handler for unexpected errors but I switch it off for the `Open` statment so I can include specific code for open failures. I have removed the code that uses `FileExists()` to test if Dummy.txt exists because it is easier to include it with the other open file error tests.

```
Sub OpenFile()

  Dim FileSysObj As Object
  Dim InputFileNum As Long

  On Error GoTo ErrorCode       ' General handler for unexpected errors

  InputFileNum = FreeFile
  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next          ' Record error in Err object and continue
  Open "Dummy.txt" For Input As InputFileNum
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case 0
      ' No error.
    Case 53           ' File does not exist
      Call MsgBox("I am unable to find ""Dummy.txt"".  List of helpful suggestions.", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    Case 75           ' Path/File access error
      Call MsgBox("It appears file ""Dummy.txt"" exists but I do not have permission to read it.", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    Case Else
      Call MsgBox("My attempt to open ""Dummy.txt"" failed with an unexpected error condition" & vbLf & _
                  "  " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
  End Select

  On Error GoTo ErrorCode      ' Restore general handler for unexpected errors

  Call MsgBox("File successfully opened", vbOKOnly)
  Close InputFileNum
  Exit Sub

ErrorCode:
  Debug.Print "Unexpected error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146864 for a long list of error codes and more information about error handling.

Comment: Thank you for those samples Tony, I worked through them and I believe I have a pretty good idea of how to implement a type of code based on yours that will fit my particular needs. The only question I have after reading all this is: is there error catching code in VBA? For example, VB.net uses Try...Catch, is there an equivalent in VBA or is programming for errors the only way to catch errors? This is probably getting outside the scope of the original question so feel free to point me to another place!

Comment: I am not sure if the questioner is told if an answer has been amended. This comment is to ensure you are told.

Comment: What time zone are you in?  Your post was at 3 am my time.

Comment: I didn't see the amendment till I looked at your post a minute ago, but I got it. I am in EST on the east coast.So your method would be to write the code and get I working the way you want and then add error handling after that?

Comment: sorry I didn't see your post about tagging til just now.

Comment: @JesseOgburn  I tell you to include my name in your comments and then forget to do it myself. Stupid! In my view jumping to a general error routine gets in the way of debugging so I only include it just before release. I did not include an example of handling errors you cannot avoid. I will add an example of this in the next few minutes.